# logstash jruby filter returns bad data

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

I trying to ingest some data into elastic with logstash. I have two strings which I have to convert to integers, and depending on whether these are even or odd, I'm creating an array with all the even or odd numbers between those numbers.

For example, for two numbers `361` and `371`, I'm creating an array of `[361, 363, 365, 367, 369, 371]`. I have a ruby script returning the array and setting the event.

This is where the strings get cleaned-

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "range" => ""}
  }
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      "lowNumber", "[^0-9]", "",
      "highNumber", "[^0-9]", ""
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is the ruby script-

```
def filter(event)
    @low = event.get('lowNumber').to_i
    @high = event.get('highNumber').to_i
    
    # check if the low number is even or odd
    filter = @low.even? ? 'even?' : 'odd?'
    
    # create an array with all numbers between low and high
    @arr = (@low..@high).to_a.select{|i| i.send(filter) }

    event.set('range', @arr)

    return [event]
end
```

I don't get any error messages but sometimes it creates the range perfectly, and other times it creates completely garbage array.

Here's an example of good data that gets returned-

```
{
            .
            .
            .
            "highNumber" => "546",
            .
            .
            "lowNumber" => "542"
            "range" => [
            [0] 542,
            [1] 544,
            [2] 546
        ],
            .
            .
}
{
                .
                .
                .
                "highNumber" => "616",
                .
                .
                "lowNumber" => "616"
                "range" => [
                [0] 616
            ],
                .
                .
    }
```

Here's what happens in lot of the cases-

```
{
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    "highNumber" => "627",
                    .
                    .
                    "lowNumber" => "627"
                    "range" => [
                       627.......13227
                ],
                    .
                    .
       }
```

This seems to have no patterns or errors. Does anyone point me to anything that'd give me an idea of what's happening here?

Comment: You are using class variables (starting with @). That means the values are persisted across events. I see no reason to do this. If you ever get an event that is missing either the highNumber or the lowNumber field then it will use the value from the previous event, which will presumably be inappropriate.

Comment: yup thank you. Fixed it. class variables were the issue

Comment: Feel free to mark as answered :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using class variables (starting with @). That means the values are persisted across events. I see no reason to do this. If you ever get an event that is missing either the highNumber or the lowNumber field then it will use the value from the previous event, which will presumably be inappropriate. I suggest you change it to

```
low = event.get('lowNumber').to_i
high = event.get('highNumber').to_i

if low and high
    # check if the low number is even or odd
    ...
end
```